# Do..Until on a never ending loop

Tags: loops, powershell

I have written a `Do..Until` statement to check whether a file exists. If the file is not there, it waits a couple seconds and checks again.

It is supposed to end when the file appears. I have tested by running the script without the file and then adding it in the folder as the script is running.

Instead of ending, it continues to loop endlessly. Can anyone see what I have missed?

```
$path = test-path "C:\Temp\test.txt"
do {    
    if (!($path)) {
        Write-Host "Not here yet..."
        Start-Sleep -s 3
    }
} until($path)

Write-Host "Files here now"
Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```

Comment: You never check again.

Comment: No idea what that means sorry, but I figured it out. Thanks

Comment: @Chris Your variable `$path` does *not* contain the check, but the *result* of the check you do in the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Test-Path` statement is evaluated in the line

```
$path = Test-Path "C:\Temp\test.txt"
```

After that the variable `$path` contains the boolean result of the evaluation. Put the actual check in your conditions:

```
$path = "C:\Temp\test.txt"
do { 
    if (-not (Test-Path $path)) {
        Write-Host "Not here yet..."
        Start-Sleep -s 3
    }
} until (Test-Path $path)
```

or define it as a function that you call in your conditions:

```
function Test-File {
    Test-Path "C:\Temp\test.txt"
}

do { 
    if (-not (Test-File)) {
        Write-Host "Not here yet..."
        Start-Sleep -s 3
    }
} until (Test-File)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. i figured it out almost immediately though. While figuring out an earlier issue involving a loose curly bracket (goodbye 2 hours of "why?!") I tried this and it obviously didn't work, so my brain filed it away under 'Do not bother'. I tried it anyways and voila!

Technically you have the correct answer, so marking it as such. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, figured it out 3 minutes after posting this (and an hour before that of frustration!).

I needed to put the variable INSIDE the Do..Until statement. Like so:

```
do{ 
    $path = test-path "C:\Temp\test.txt"
    if (!($path))   
        {Write-Host "Not here yet..."
        start-sleep -s 3}       
    }
until($path)
    Write-Host "Files here now"
    Write-Host "Press any key to continue ..."
    $x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")
```